# Mean of binary random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,...,X_m$ be $m$ random variables which take value 0 or 1. They are dependent in the sense that $E[X_i X_j]\leq\delta$ for some real number $\delta\in[0,1]$ and every distinct $i,j$. The goal is to get a tight upper bound of $I=E[X_1+\ldots+X_m]$, i.e., the mean of their summation.

By taking the second moment $I^2\leq E[(X_1+\ldots+X_m)^2] = I + 2\sum_{i< j}E[X_i X_j]\leq I+m(m-1)\delta$, so $I\leq 1+m(m-1)\delta$. If $\delta=0$, this bound is 1. The question is whether the bound is tight; I suspect it may be possible to get $1+O(m\delta)$.

Comment: What is meant by that inner product notation?  Do you really mean $E[X_iX_j] \leq \delta$ ?

Comment: In your second paragraph, $m(m-1)$ terms suddenly turn into $m(m-1)/2$ terms, An inequality $\leq \delta$ turns into equality, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes $\langle X_iX_j\rangle=E[X_iX_j]$. I missed the factor 2 and corrected it.

Comment: The mean of the sum $=mP(X_k=1)$, assuming all have the same distribution.  Your statement has an error.  Also notation - you need to make clear what $I$ is.  Is it the sum of the random variables (as you express it) or the sum of the means?

Comment: $I$ is the sum of the means. I will change $\langle\cdot\rangle$ to $E[\cdot]$ in order to avoid confusions.

Comment: For my part, I actually like the inner product notation:  it's the geometric view of random variables as vectors in a Hilbert space. With that in mind we have $\|X_i\|^2=E[X_i^2]= E[X_i]$ for binary r.v.s. Hence your expression of interest is $\sum_i \|X_i\|^2$, and you're looking for an upper bound subject to $\langle X_i,X_j\rangle \leq \delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computations show that $I^2-I\leq m(m-1)\delta$. The function $x\mapsto x^2-x$ is negative over $(0,1)$ and positive increasing when $x> 1$. Since $I\geq 0$ and $m(m-1)\delta>0$, $$I^2-I\leq m(m-1)\delta\iff I\in \left[0, \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4m(m-1)\delta}}{2}\right]$$
So you effectively get an upper bound in $O(m\sqrt \delta)$.

Comment: Your first part makes sense.  For the second part on phantom, how do you claim that last inequality $\sum_{i \neq j} E[X_i]E[X_j] \leq m(m-1)\delta$? If $X_i$ and $X_j$ are negatively correlated then we can have $E[X_i]E[X_j]> E[X_iX_j]=\delta$.  Also, the equation you eventually derive $(\sum_iE[ X_i])^2 = \sum_i E[X_i]^2 + \sum_{i\neq j} E[X_i]E[X_j]$ (the second-to-last-line) is immediately true without using phantom.  It does not look like that phantom stuff is useful in this context.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, there was a mistake. I claim $$E(\sum_i X_i X_i') + \sum_{i\neq j}E(X_iX_j')
= \sum_i E(X_i)^2 + \sum_{i\neq j}E(X_iX_j)$$ because $(X_i,X_j')$ has the same distribution as $(X_i,X_j)$, hence $X_iX_j'$ and $X_iX_j$ have the same distribution. The phantom technique yields a sharper but useless bound.

Comment: Actually I don't think that my claim about $(X_i,X_j')$ and $(X_i,X_j)$  is true...

Comment: I see you have removed that problematic part on phantom variables so I have plus-1d.